# Напечатать число которое начинается с 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно вернуть число в котором 8 символов включая 0. Почему то он вначале отбрасивается, но он есть.
код:

```
for r in result:
    rd = r.get_text()
    rw = len(rd)
    while rw==8:
         print(rd)
         break
```

результат:

- 12345678
- 1234567
- 23456789

должно быть:

- 12345678
- **0**1234567
- 23456789

Comment: str(rd).zfill(8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
print(rd)
```

напишите

```
print(f"{rd:08}")
```

(для Питон 3.6+), или

```
print("{:08}".format(rd))
```

(для Питон 3.0+).

---

*Объяснение:*

в `:08` число `8` значит количество позиций и `0` значит, что для коротких чисел будут слева добавлены не пробелы, а *нули*.

Answer (score 0):

```
rd = ["12345678", "1234567", "23456789"]

print("{:0>8} \n{:0>8} \n{:0>8}".format(*rd))
12345678 
01234567 
23456789
```